# find element by class name (node js)

Tags: javascript, html, css

For my tool there is a button with a dropdown list if you click the button.

The button is using a class : countryButton-1cNDvB button-f2h6uQ lookFilled-yCfaCM colorPrimary-2AuQVo sizeSmall-wU2dO- grow-2sR_-F

NO ID!

I want the tool to click the button simply way, but it doesn't click the button in my tool.

I've tried:

```
<button onclick="alert('clicked')" type="button" class="countryButton-1cNDvB button-f2h6uQ lookFilled-yCfaCM colorPrimary-2AuQVo sizeSmall-wU2dO- grow-2sR_-F" style="" xpath="62"><div class="contents-3ca1mk countryButtonInner-1o5lfS"><div class="flex-2S1XBF flex-3BkGQD horizontal-112GEH horizontal-1Piu5- flex-3BkGQD directionRow-2Iu2A9 justifyCenter-rrurWZ alignStretch-Uwowzr noWrap-hBpHBz countryCodeContainer-31fe5z marginReset-28ZZyF" style="flex: 1 1 auto;"><div class="plusSign-1BkjXr">+</div><div class="countryCode-2RFA3i">1</div></div><svg class="transition-30IQBn directionRight-2cNgoe" width="16" height="16" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path class="phoneFieldExpand-1CqrEb" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M7 10L12 15 17 10" aria-hidden="true" onclick="location.href='http://www.google.com'"></path></svg></div></button>


</script>

<script>
document.querySelector("button.countryButton-1cNDvB").click();
</script>
```

On w3schools.com it works when I run the code it indeed clicks the button. But when ever i implement the same code in my script it doesnt click the button. Is there any reason for this?

The tool is for account registration. It does find the button but it is just not clicking it.

```
 
            //  Click on the contry button
            try{
            await delay(1000)
            //await page.waitForSelector("#app-mount > div:nth-child(6) > div.layer-1Ixpg3 > div > div > div.flex-2S1XBF.flex-3BkGQD.horizontal-112GEH.horizontal-1Piu5-.flex-3BkGQD.directionRow-2Iu2A9.justifyStart-2Mwniq.alignCenter-14kD11.noWrap-hBpHBz.phoneField-3NAPDv.elevationLow-26BbEG.field-3rN-Ip > button.countryButton-1cNDvB.button-f2h6uQ.lookFilled-yCfaCM.colorGrey-2iAG-B.sizeSmall-wU2dO-.grow-2sR_-F"); 
            await page.evaluate('document.querySelector("#app-mount > div:nth-child(6) > div.layer-1Ixpg3 > div > div > div.flex-2S1XBF.flex-3BkGQD.horizontal-112GEH.horizontal-1Piu5-.flex-3BkGQD.directionRow-2Iu2A9.justifyStart-2Mwniq.alignCenter-14kD11.noWrap-hBpHBz.phoneField-3NAPDv.elevationLow-26BbEG.field-3rN-Ip > button.countryButton-1cNDvB.button-f2h6uQ.lookFilled-yCfaCM.colorGrey-2iAG-B.sizeSmall-wU2dO-.grow-2sR_-F").click()');
            await sleep(300);
        } catch(error) { }
        try{
        //  Enter the contry name
        await page.waitForSelector("#app-mount > div:nth-child(6) > div.layer-1Ixpg3 > div > div > div.flex-2S1XBF.flex-3BkGQD.horizontal-112GEH.horizontal-1Piu5-.flex-3BkGQD.directionRow-2Iu2A9.justifyStart-2Mwniq.alignCenter-14kD11.noWrap-hBpHBz.phoneField-3NAPDv.elevationLow-26BbEG.field-3rN-Ip > div > div.popoutListInput-1w4TxY.size14-y91Il2.container-2oNtJn.small-1uriao > div > input", {timeout: 5000 }); 
        await page.type('#app-mount > div:nth-child(6) > div.layer-1Ixpg3 > div > div > div.flex-2S1XBF.flex-3BkGQD.horizontal-112GEH.horizontal-1Piu5-.flex-3BkGQD.directionRow-2Iu2A9.justifyStart-2Mwniq.alignCenter-14kD11.noWrap-hBpHBz.phoneField-3NAPDv.elevationLow-26BbEG.field-3rN-Ip > div > div.popoutListInput-1w4TxY.size14-y91Il2.container-2oNtJn.small-1uriao > div > input',phone_contry);
        await sleep(300);
        }catch(error) {}
        try{
            //await page.waitForSelector("#app-mount > div:nth-child(6) > div.layer-1Ixpg3 > div > div > div.flex-2S1XBF.flex-3BkGQD.horizontal-112GEH.horizontal-1Piu5-.flex-3BkGQD.directionRow-2Iu2A9.justifyStart-2Mwniq.alignCenter-14kD11.noWrap-hBpHBz.phoneField-3NAPDv.elevationLow-26BbEG.field-3rN-Ip > div > div.phoneFieldScroller-2DblLb.auto-2K3UW5.scrollerBase-_bVAAt > div:nth-child(1)"); 
            await page.evaluate('document.querySelector("#app-mount > div:nth-child(6) > div.layer-1Ixpg3 > div > div > div.flex-2S1XBF.flex-3BkGQD.horizontal-112GEH.horizontal-1Piu5-.flex-3BkGQD.directionRow-2Iu2A9.justifyStart-2Mwniq.alignCenter-14kD11.noWrap-hBpHBz.phoneField-3NAPDv.elevationLow-26BbEG.field-3rN-Ip > div > div.phoneFieldScroller-2DblLb.auto-2K3UW5.scrollerBase-_bVAAt > div:nth-child(1)").click()');
            await sleep(300);
        } catch(error) { }
        try{
            //  Enter phone number
            //await page.waitForSelector("#app-mount > div:nth-child(6) > div.layer-1Ixpg3 > div > div > div.flex-2S1XBF.flex-3BkGQD.horizontal-112GEH.horizontal-1Piu5-.flex-3BkGQD.directionRow-2Iu2A9.justifyStart-2Mwniq.alignCenter-14kD11.noWrap-hBpHBz.phoneField-3NAPDv.elevationLow-26BbEG.field-3rN-Ip > input"); 
            await page.type('#app-mount > div:nth-child(6) > div.layer-1Ixpg3 > div > div > div.flex-2S1XBF.flex-3BkGQD.horizontal-112GEH.horizontal-1Piu5-.flex-3BkGQD.directionRow-2Iu2A9.justifyStart-2Mwniq.alignCenter-14kD11.noWrap-hBpHBz.phoneField-3NAPDv.elevationLow-26BbEG.field-3rN-Ip > input',phone_number)
            await sleep(300);
        } catch(error) { }
```

This is a piece of the code. It is supposed to reconize the CountryButton and click it. It does reckonize it but doesn't click it.

Comment: What is this tool of yours? How is Node.js related - are you running this code in the backend? What exactly doesn't work - does it not find the button or just not clicking it? Do you have a [mcve]?

Comment: It depends where the code is and how you're calling it. Is it an external script you're calling in? Is it in a script tag in the header? You need to ensure that the DOM has had a chance to load because that code is getting executed immediately. So either [`defer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#attr-defer) the load, use the [`DOMContentLoaded`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/DOMContentLoaded_event) event, or move the script to just before the `</body>` tag.

Comment: (And, as VLAZ pointed out, remove the tags - node, jquery - from your question if they're not relevant).

Comment: @VLAZ It creates an account on a website and I need to fill in my country. It's a dropdown menu button where I want to select the country Indonesia. The default is set on USA and for some reason i can not manage it to change the country. The dropdown button only uses a class="countryButton-1cNDvB button-f2h6uQ lookFilled-yCfaCM colorPrimary-2AuQVo sizeSmall-wU2dO- grow-2sR_-F"

Answer (score -1):

try this:-
remove `button` from `button.countryButton-1cNDvB` as shown below

```
<script>
document.querySelector(".countryButton-1cNDvB").click();
</script>
```

this should do it.

Comment: doesnt do the trick :( my goals is that the script selects the drop down button . For some reason it seems not to find the dropdown button..

Answer (score -1):

Alright, try swapping the two `<script>` tags, like this:

```
<script>
  document.querySelector("button.countryButton-1cNDvB").click();
</script>

<button onclick="alert('clicked')" type="button" class="countryButton-1cNDvB button-f2h6uQ lookFilled-yCfaCM colorPrimary-2AuQVo sizeSmall-wU2dO- grow-2sR_-F" style="" xpath="62"><div class="contents-3ca1mk countryButtonInner-1o5lfS"><div class="flex-2S1XBF flex-3BkGQD horizontal-112GEH horizontal-1Piu5- flex-3BkGQD directionRow-2Iu2A9 justifyCenter-rrurWZ alignStretch-Uwowzr noWrap-hBpHBz countryCodeContainer-31fe5z marginReset-28ZZyF" style="flex: 1 1 auto;"><div class="plusSign-1BkjXr">+</div><div class="countryCode-2RFA3i">1</div></div><svg class="transition-30IQBn directionRight-2cNgoe" width="16" height="16" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path class="phoneFieldExpand-1CqrEb" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M7 10L12 15 17 10" aria-hidden="true" onclick="location.href='http://www.google.com'"></path></svg></div></button>
```

As I can see it, your js first runs the code above and then the one below, so basically the code below can't access button on top.

If this doesn't solve the problem, be sure to check all pathing, tags and indentation.

Comment: Why is the `<button>` tag in the JavaScript code? This is not valid JavaScript.

Comment: Pathing is right since there is only 1 class with that name. I used to write my tool in python but that got patched by the site im using the tool on, so I tried rewrite it in nodejs. For some reason with the same class it doesn't work in nodejs. It's a dropdown button where you can select a country. My goals is to click the dropdown button and  select country Indonesia, for some reason the dropdown doesnt show up and it seems like it's ignoring the dropdown button

Comment: @ArnavThorat oops, that was a big typo, kind-of

Comment: @Jesse have you considered maeking it another way, to use css instead of js? of course, you'd have to change a bit of code, but then you'll know what's going on.
Or, maybe it would be the best to use <select> tag, and style it to look the way you want